# woocommerce-ordering template location

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove element style from woocommerce ordering form, but i couldnt find the form template ( where the inside element style is given).
I only found out **woocommerce-ordering.php** but there are no classes or styles inside it.
My purpose is 
For Example 
`<span class="customSelectInner" style="width: 218px; display: inline-block;">Default Sorting</span>` 
I want to set the width to auto , I know it can be achieved by using `!important`.
But it loads the element style first , then switch width to auto , so it looks very weird.
So i have to edit the template file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find file for it then just use simple jQuery for this

```
jQuery(".customSelectInner").css("width","auto")
```

Comment: nope , unable to change it .  i tried removing attribute style too.